# Time invariant system with integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, signal-processing

I have this signal $ y(t)= \int_{\infty}^{\infty} x(\tau ) z(t -\tau ) d\tau $ and I have to find if this is time invariant or not. I have some problems with the change of variable. I don’t know if I have to change the variable also into z argument. I made it but my result is that this is time variant and the correct result is the opposite. Thank you so much

Comment: The system could be time varying, but the convolution of the two signals is not necessarily time invariant.  It depends on the properties of the functions being integrated.  You shouldn't need any change of variable.  Do you have a specific function for $x$ and $z$?  How did you show it was time varying?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that $  z( θ) = 0 $ for $ θ < 0 $. To demonstrate this I started to delay Only $ x (\tau) $ and after to delay $ y(t) = t-t_0 $ so I put $t-t_0 $ instead of every t. But if $ t - \tau < 0 $ the second function is 0